# `Type Error: undefined is not a function (it is undefined)` on curly bracket comment block

Tags: typescript, react-native

A sudden error appeared on this line after upgrading from RN 70.6 to RN 72.4 on `react-native` iOS and android.

**Error Example:**

```
const HeaderContainer = ({ headerComponent }: { headerComponent: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {/* comment block causing error */}
      {headerComponent}
    </View>
  )
}
```

If I delete the line `{/* comment block causing error */}`, or wrap comment line & `headerComponent` with `Fragment` or another component, or add more sibling to `headerComponent` the error disappears.

**Work Example:**

- delete the line `{/* comment block causing error */}`

```
const HeaderContainer = ({ headerComponent }: { headerComponent: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {headerComponent}
    </View>
  )
}
```

- wrap comment line & `headerComponent` with `Fragment` or another component

```
const HeaderContainer = ({ headerComponent }: { headerComponent: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <>
        {/* comment block causing error */}
        {headerComponent}
      </>
    </View>
  )
}
```

- add more sibling to `headerComponent`

```
const HeaderContainer = ({ headerComponent }: { headerComponent: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {/* comment block causing error */}
      <Text>Sibling Component<Text>
      {headerComponent}
    </View>
  )
}
```

The error also appeared on [this library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view/blob/master/src/utils.tsx) line 10, with the same mentioned pattern.

TSX should not be an error when a comment block is placed beside a single child component.

Notes: Sadly when I tried to replicate the issue on the fresh project, the issue did not appear